# how to format web page content loaded from javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a webpage that displays a web form whose source is javascript.

By default it places this form in the upper left corner of the screen. How to center it horizontally and vertically on the screen?

I'm confused because the block is in the `<script>` section rather than `<body>`.

The form is generated by my email marketing service provider, and I don't have access to its code.

The complete html file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://app...."></script>  
    </head>     
    <body>       
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try using css? You could use css on the whole document (html tag) and try using margin auto and other css properties to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without actually seeing what your JavaScript is doing this is difficult to answer, however the generalized answer to your problem is to use CSS.  You can do so within the head section of your html document using the `<style>` tag (see code below) or using `<link>` to add an external stylesheet.

Check out W3 to get you started learning more about CSS: http://www.w3schools.com/css/

Actual CSS attributes you will need may vary, but [this article](http://joshbroton.com/absolute-positioning-and-horizontal-vertical-centering/) shows use of `transform: translate` to center an element vertically and horizontally.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            /* this is a class you would add to the parent HTML tag of your form */
            form {
                position: relative;
                left: 50%;
                top: 50%;
                transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
            }          
        </style> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://app...."></script>  
    </head>     
    <body>       
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @phamousphil, I added the script section as above but it had no effect. Is this because there may be CSS used in the javascript form and that CSS is closer to the form than mine is and thus mine gets overwritten? (update: I added  `!important` to each of the 4 form styles and this had no effect either)

Comment: @user46688 yes this is a possibility.  Again, without seeing all of your code this is difficult to diagnose.  First, check that you have added `class="form"` to the parent html tag of your form.  If you can put your code or a prototype of your code in a http://jsfiddle.net/ that greatly helps with Stackoverflow collaboration and problem solving.

Comment: Note: My complete HTML file is posted in the original question. I don't have access to whatever gets loaded in by javascript, so I guess we're going to assume since it's a form that it uses the `form` tag somewhere. I'm can't add `class="form"` to the code loaded by javascript.

Comment: I am referring to the code in the linked JavaScript.

Comment: you shouldn't need to add the form class, the generic form selector  will work fine

Comment: @AlanSutherland good point, thanks for the call out.  Edit made to answer.

Comment: @phamousphil, changing `relative` to `fixed` causes the form to center vertically, but the width is the whole width of the screen. Adding a `max-width` property fixes that. Works in the Chrome and FF, but not Safari (version 7, which places the form's upper-left corner in the center of the screen).

Comment: What happens if you change `max-width` to `width`?

Comment: The form width expands to fill the screen's width. Setting height or max-height has no effect.

Comment: Try setting width to the number of pixels you desire (e.g. `width: 200px;`)  If that works in Safari 7 you may want to add some conditional code to handle that browser.

Answer (score 3):

Is it your javascript file or are you loading in an external file which creates the form? You can add classes/id's to javascript generated markup which is one way you could target it but you should be able to target and centre it just using:

```
form {display: block; margin: 0 auto; width: 100%}
```

Comment: The javascript is loaded from my email marketing service provider who creates it, so it's a black box to me. Could you give an example of `You can add classes/id's to javascript generated markup`, or is that not possible here?

Comment: then try adding the CSS I've added to target all forms

Comment: I added your CSS but it had no effect. Wouldn't this CSS that I add be overwritten by the CSS used by the javascript?

Comment: you can add classes/id's if you're writing the script as well but in this instance as you're loading in an external script you have no control over it so this wouldn't be possible

Comment: Sure, I understand that. And the closest CSS to the element wins right? So, are there any options to force it, like `!important`? (I'm somewhat of a newbie) We can't include `class=""` or `style=""` inside `<script>` right?

Comment: !important wont work in this case, why are you loading in an external form script? you could try build the form yourself which would make things easier

Comment: that's funny. It's advertised as a feature by the email marketing provider... they provide a template and editor, let you build what you like, and link the form on your website with this code. This way they can track your conversion rate, who clicked it, when, etc. But you're right, for developers it'd be easier for them to do it from scratch.